# Rigify horse armature: hind leg bones seem wrong; tweak also on wrong layer?

Tags: armature, bones, rigify, layers

I tried configurate the armature after I saw it was kind of broken. What I did was only to rename a few hind leg bones and subdivide one, because that joint was missing in the preset. As I read in the plugin, is should be able to add those correctly. It also created the metarig, but the problem is still the same. The controls are displayed wrong in the FK display. Is there anything I can do to fix it? I am willing to edit the python script if I get any assistance... Also, the hind left tweak bones are on the layer of the tail bones... but on the layer view they are shwon on the correct one... I am a bit confused.
Pictures for explaination see below.
[image: wrong hind legs rig + tweak layer bones on wrong layer (they count to the tail???)]
[image: metarig]

Tried to modify the rigify layers. Now I get this message when I click on generate rig in the panel: 
[image: rigify error]

Answer (score 1):

I havent used the Rigify animal rigs but there are a few things I can share. Keep in mind that Rigify is tricky to customize. If there are too much edits it will not work right.

After adding bones in edit mode you have to let the rig know there are more bones in the chain. On the metarig go to Pose Mode and click on the Thigh bone. Now go to the Bone Properties panel on your right and find Rigify type> Limb Segments. Experiment with adding numbers here and generating the rig until you find it works.

In that panel you can also click on the layer where you want the tweak bones.

Comment: Thank you, I found that option, but it creates an error message. Have no idea what needs to be changed now.